# How could we choose the sdk FBX Exporter version?

Tags: .fbx

is there a way to check and eventually choose the FBX format version we export in Blender ?

For reference purpose, we need the 2019.0 file format version because of Touchdesigner requirements : https://docs.derivative.ca/FBX_COMP

Comment: You might need to modify the current `io_scene_fbx` addon, If you look in this [file](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/BA/browse/master/io_scene_fbx/fbx_utils.py$22) you could possibly just modify the `FBX VERSION` constant and maybe modify a few other settings and then use that addon as your custom FBX exporter.

Comment: Blender does not use the FBX SDK, it only has a python implementation of parts that are publicly known. Strict adherence to the FBX specification of any SDK version is not possible because it is not a publicly documented file format.